# How to detect a mouse click on a TListView Group header?

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 and VCL. How can I detect a click or double-click on a Group header in a `TListView`? Not on a Column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is based on Remy and Victoria comments, with an old answer by Bummi at https://www.entwickler-ecke.de/topic_ListViewEigenschaften+Delphi+vs+C+SubItems+auslesen_110307,0.html.

Few comments for the solution:

1. Subclass is an option but could be implemented with Form's ListView1MouseDown event too, which is a little bit simpler.
2. tLVHitTestInfo & LVM_HITTEST are defined in Winapi.CommCtrl.

   ```
   Uses
     Winapi.CommCtrl; // For LVM_HITTEST
   ```
3. LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER value should be defined manually. I didn't find it inside any Delphi unit. It is the identifier that a Group header was clicked. It should be verified with LVHitTestInfo.flags. It is Valid for Windows Vista and above.

   ```
   const
     LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER = $10000000;
   ```
4. LVHitTestInfo.iGroup Doesn't work! I don't know the reason. Originally, I thought it should be the Group index.

The example has a form with ListView on it, the style is ViewStyle = vsReport. A mouse click on a group header will invoke a message dialog with the group index. Here is the detailed code:

```
    Uses Winapi.CommCtrl;

    procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    const
      LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER = $10000000; // It is Valid for Windows Vista and above.
    var
      HTI: tLVHitTestInfo; // Defined on Winapi.CommCtrl
      nGroupInx: integer;
    begin
      HTI.pt     := point(X, Y); // Add cursor position
      nGroupInx  := SendMessage(ListView1.Handle, LVM_HITTEST, -1, LPARAM(@HTI)); // Return an Item
      if nGroupInx <> -1 then // Is an Item found?
        if (HTI.flags and LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER) = LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER then // Is it a Group Header?
            ShowMessage('Clicked Group header:' + ' ' + nGroupInx.ToString);
    end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Subclass the ListView to catch click related messages (`WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)`, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, etc), and then send a [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761099.aspx) message to the ListView specifying the client coordinates of the click.

Per the documentation, you have to set the message's `wParam` to -1 to get group information, which means you have to send the `LVM_HITTEST` message by calling `SendMessage()` directly, you can't use the [`ListView_HitTest()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775028.aspx) function, which sets `wParam` to 0.

When clicking on a Group header, the populated `LVHITTESTINFO` will have the `LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER` flag enabled, and the `iItem` field will be the group index.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but are you sure that list view receives notifications like `NM_CLICK` when a group header is clicked?

Comment: @Victoria I haven't tested it yet so no, I'm not sure. That is why I mentioned other messages, too

Comment: @Victoria I tested it now, and indeed `NM_CLICK` and `NM_DBCLK` are not issued when clicking on a group header, but `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` are